# Compare Checkbox List values for Nothing Checked through LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using below code for filtering on the basis of Checkboxlist but, filter is not working if I don't select anything. It has to show all the values if I don't checked any value.

Below is the code for that :

```
var selectedIds = chklstDepartment.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(item => item.Selected).Select(item => item.Value).ToArray();
                        List<LessonLearnDetails> objLessonDetails = objLessonDashboard.getLessonLearntDetails();
                        var searchData = objLessonDetails.Where(i => (ddlAsset.SelectedValue == "0") || (i._Asset.AssetID == ddlAsset.SelectedValue))
                    .Where(i => (ddlAuditType.SelectedValue == "0") || (i._Audit.AuditTypeID == ddlAuditType.SelectedValue))
                    .Where(i => (chklstDepartment.SelectedValue == "0") || (selectedIds.Contains(i._Department.DepartmentID)))
                    .Where(i => (ddlCategory.SelectedValue == "0") || (i._Category.CategoryID == ddlCategory.SelectedValue))
                      .Where(i => (ddlStartYear.SelectedItem.Text == "--Select All--") || (Convert.ToInt32(i._Year.StartYear) >= Convert.ToInt32(ddlStartYear.SelectedItem.Text)))
                .Where(i => (ddlEndYear.SelectedItem.Text == "--Select All--") || (Convert.ToInt32(i._Year.EndYear) <= Convert.ToInt32(ddlEndYear.SelectedItem.Text)))
                    .Distinct().ToList();
                        BindGrid(searchData);
```

Comment: what's the current result if you don't checked any value?

Comment: count is coming 0

Comment: when not checking, are you sure `SelectedValues` are "0" or "--Select All--"? how can you prove?

Comment: It was coming "", I've checked. It doesn't comes in mind, instead did many changes.
Thanks...

Comment: if values are not "0" or "--Select All--", you should change code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "" in place of "0".

```
chklstDepartment.SelectedValue == ""
```